# Copying data from a local database to a remote one

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm writing a system at the moment that needs to copy data from a clients locally hosted SQL database to a hosted server database. Most of the data in the local database is copied to the live one, though optimisations are made to reduce the amount of actual data required to be sent.

What is the best way of sending this data from one database to the other? At the moment I can see a few possibly options, none of them yet stand out as being the prime candidate.

- Replication, though this is not ideal, and we cannot expect it to be supported in the version of SQL we use on the hosted environment.
- Linked server, copying data direct - a slow and somewhat insecure method
- Webservices to transmit the data
- Exporting the data we require as XML and transferring to the server to be imported in bulk.

The data copied goes into copies of the tables, without identity fields, so data can be inserted/updated without any violations in that respect. This data transfer does not have to be done at the database level, it can be done from .net or other facilities.

**More information**

The frequency of the updates will vary completely on how often records are updated. But the basic idea is that if a record is changed then the user can publish it to the live database. Alternatively we'll record the changes and send them across in a batch on a configurable frequency.

The amount of records we're talking are around 4000 rows per table for the core tables (product catalog) at the moment, but this is completely variable dependent on the client we deploy this to as each would have their own product catalog, ranging from 100's to 1000's of products. To clarify, each client is on a separate local/hosted database combination, they are not combined into one system.

As well as the individual publishing of items, we would also require a complete re-sync of data to be done on demand.

Another aspect of the system is that some of the data being copied from the local server is stored in a secondary database, so we're effectively merging the data from two databases into the one live database.

Comment: Just a heads up that you can keep the identity fields and insert them into the other database by issuing the command `SET IDENTITY INSERT ON` when you start. Remember to turn it off when you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I opted for a set of triggers to capture data modifications to a change log table. There is then an application that polls this table and generates XML files for submission to a webservice running at the remote location.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm biased. I have to admit. I'd like to hypnotize you into shelling out for SQL Compare to do this. I've been faced with exactly this sort of problem in all its open-ended frightfulness. I got a copy of SQL Compare and never looked back. SQL Compare is actually a silly name for a piece of software that synchronizes databases It will also do it from the command line once you have got a working project together with all the right knobs and buttons. Of course, you can only do this for reasonably small databases, but it really is a tool I wouldn't want to be seen in public without.

My only concern with your requirements is where you are collecting product catalogs from a number of clients. If they are all in separate tables, then all is fine, whereas if they are all in the same table, then this would make things more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

How much data are you talking about? how many 'client' dbs are there? and how often does it need to happen? The answers to those questions will make a big difference on the path you should take.

Answer (score 0):

There is an almost infinite number of solutions for this problem. In order to narrow it down, you'd have to tell us a bit about your requirements and priorities.

Bulk operations would probably cover a wide range of scenarios, and you should add that to the top of your list.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Data Transformation Services (DTS) for this. You could create a DTS package for appending and one for re-creating the data.

It is possible to invoke DTS package operations from your code so you may want to create a wrapper to control the packages that you can call from your application.